How unit test asyncio.run function with pytest?
Suppose I have an async celery task below;
@celery.task
def clean_db():
    """Auto clean db"""
    asyncio.run(fetch_and_clean_db())

And I want to use pytest to test the fetch_and_clean_db is called once the task clean_db is called ?
How best can I test this with pytest ?
